# change the root in embedded document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is my output :

```
 [
        {
            "_id": "5f637432c57a7d0017af1421",
            "project": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f637774c57a7d0017af1423",
                    "projectName": "Notification project",
                    "licenseType": "agricultural and biological engineering",
                    "location": "chennai",
                    "description": "Sample data Sample data Sample data Sample data Sample data.",
                    "duration": 70,
                    "createdAt": "2020-09-17T14:49:24.860Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-09-17T14:49:24.860Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f63965166bca1001783fbb4",
                    "projectName": "Sample project 1",
                    "licenseType": "civil",
                    "location": "chennai",
                    "description": "Sample data 1",
                    "duration": 30,
                    "createdAt": "2020-09-18T17:01:05.929Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T17:01:05.929Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f63967866bca1001783fbb9",
                    "projectName": "Sample project 2",
                    "licenseType": "nuclear",
                    "location": "chennai",
                    "description": "Sample data 2",
                    "duration": 80,
                    "createdAt": "2020-09-18T17:01:44.375Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T17:01:44.375Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I just want to have the **project** as the new root. I tried $replaceRoot but it does not work. It says it needs an object but its receiving a string. Maybe I'm not doing it the right way.

NOTE: I used Aggregation framework to get the output shown above.

Appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Please try `[ { $unwind: "$project" }, { $replaceWith: "$project" } ]` [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2nkSPOQ3J0Z).

Comment: can you please describe here which type of output you want?

Comment: @PrakashHarvani I would like my output to be like this : { "project" : [{....} , {.....}] }.

Comment: @Rfroes87 can you please tell me why do i need to unwind it ? Appreciate your help

Comment: @Sushmit If you do it step-by-step, you will see that, after `$unwind`, you now have 3 documents containing a single `$project` document instead of one containing an array of 3 documents; with that, using `$replaceWith` - which is an alias for `$replaceRoot` - will work because, as the documentation states, it will "promote an embedded **document** to the top-level". That's why you need `$unwind`.